# How to play single notes from midi file in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, midi

There is an image of musical instrument at the screen in my app. I want to play a single note from predefined midi file when the image is touched. So if you touch the image continuously, you can hear some nice music.

The Music and Sound classes of LibGDX do not allow  to play midi files note by note. Timer is not an option because duration of notes may vary.

So, how to play single notes from midi file in LibGDX?

Comment: Libgdx uses the Android MediaPlayer class for loading and playing sounds and music. MediaPlayer does not support playing midi files note by note. You will have to implement your own solution. You might be able to harness JetPlayer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html